How can I effectivly speed up my loops through Pandas for the belove code?
I have been looking at using multiprocessing, cyton and numba to speed up the below part of my code, but I just cannot figure it out. My current conclusion is that my code is ineffective, although it took me a lot of efford to get the code together and working, it's just not at all effective and would appreciate some help on the matter: Below code takes about 78 seconds to run.
daten={'Contract':Contract_Name,'Product':Products,'Relative':Relative_Name,'Start_Date':Start_Dates,'End_Date':End_Dates,'Relevant':Relevant, 'Volume':Volumes,'Hours':Hours}
df=pd.DataFrame(daten)

Matrix=[]
pt = process_time()
df['Start_Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])
h_prof['DeliveryStart']=pd.to_datetime(h_prof['DeliveryStart'])

for j in h_prof['DeliveryStart']:
        Vector=[]
        idx2=h_prof['DeliveryStart'].to_list().index(j)
        for i in df['Start_Date']:
            check=False
            idx=df['Start_Date'].to_list().index(i)
            if (i<=j)and(df['End_Date'][idx]>=j):
                if df['Product'][idx]=='bunn':
                    check=True
                elif h_prof['P_OP'][idx2]=='P':
                    check=True
            if check==True:
                Vector.append(1)
            else:
                Vector.append(0)
        Matrix.append(Vector)

Thanks a lot in advance!
H_prof df:
RangeIndex: 8760 entries, 0 to 8759
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------          --------------  -----         
 0   Name            8760 non-null   object        
 1   Id              8760 non-null   int64         
 2   DeliveryStart   8760 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 3   DeliveryEnd     8760 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 4   Quantity        8760 non-null   float64       
 5   QuantityUnit    8760 non-null   object        
 6   Time            8760 non-null   object        
 7   Hour            8760 non-null   int64         
 8   WkDay           8760 non-null   int64         
 9   P_OP            8760 non-null   object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(1), int64(3), object(4)
memory usage: 684.5+ KB


at each iteration you recreate a list from your Series (for idx2 an idx) which looks like time consuming. Can you share input dataframe (let's say 5-10 rows).

also how big are your both dataframes in the real use case?

Looks like a self merge.

@Ben.T Please see revised question,, does that help?

@QuangHoang Not sure what that means,, can you please explain?

What is h_prof?

Fast solution using numpy
You can use numpy np.ufunc.outer and broadcasting to do your task in a really fast manner:
import numpy as np

m = (
    np.less_equal.outer(df['Start_Date'].to_numpy(), 
                        h_prof['DeliveryStart'].to_numpy())
    & np.greater_equal.outer(df['End_Date'].to_numpy(), 
                             h_prof['DeliveryStart'].to_numpy())
    & (np.equal(df['Product'].to_numpy(), 'bunn')[:,np.newaxis]
       | np.equal(h_prof['P_OP'].to_numpy(), 'P')[np.newaxis,:])
).astype(int).T.tolist()

The np.less_equal is the equivalent to this condition (i<=j) in your code, the np.greater_equal to this condition and(df['End_Date'][idx]>=j), the first np.equal to this condition df['Product'][idx]=='bunn' and the last np.equal is for this condition h_prof['P_OP'][idx2]=='P'. Knowing that the last 2 conditions have to be broadcasted using np.newaxis to fit in the final output dimension.
In terms of gain, with the shapes for datasets being in my tests
df.shape, h_prof.shape
#((120, 3), (140, 2))

you have a gain 1000 times almost with this version and yours.
Answer improving your code
There are improvements to be done keeping the same style of coding.
First instead of doing a loop on the series and then get the index in the only goal to get the value in another column later:
for j in h_prof['DeliveryStart']:
        ...
        idx2=h_prof['DeliveryStart'].to_list().index(j)
        ...
           elif h_prof['P_OP'][idx2]=='P'

one can do:
for j, pop in h_prof[['DeliveryStart', 'P_OP']].to_numpy():

which becomes interesting in terms of speed when your data is above hundreds or rows. The same can be done with the second loop:
for i in df['Start_Date']:
    ...
    idx=df['Start_Date'].to_list().index(i)
    if ...(df['End_Date'][idx]>=j):
        if df['Product'][idx]=='bunn':

that becomes
for i, e, prod in df[['Start_Date', 'End_Date','Product']].to_numpy():

So with an overall code being:
Matrix1=[]
df['Start_Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])
h_prof['DeliveryStart']=pd.to_datetime(h_prof['DeliveryStart'])

for j, pop in h_prof[['DeliveryStart', 'P_OP']].to_numpy():
        Vector=[]
        for i, e, prod in df[['Start_Date', 'End_Date','Product']].to_numpy():
            if ((i<=j) and (e>=j)
               and ((prod=='bunn') or (pop=='P'))): 
                Vector.append(1)
            else: 
                Vector.append(0)
        Matrix1.append(Vector)

you already get a speed up of x15 with dataset sizes of
df.shape, h_prof.shape
#((120, 3), (140, 2))

knowing that the gain should increase with the size.
Last point if you want to increase gain using this style, these two conditions (prod=='bunn') or (pop=='P') are duplicated, they could be done outside of the loops.

Thanks for your comprehensive answer! Speed is of great essence to me, trying out your numpy solution.

Both your solutions took the time down from 110 secs to 33 secs. Much appreciated!

@cJc 33sec for the first solution with numpy... seems really long! just to be sure, m is equivalent to Matrix. no loop for involve with this solution!

Sorry, my bad. I timed the whole script. The part in question was previouse 75s now less that 1s with np and just under 2s with your improved code!  Can you please elaborate on what you wrote: "(prod=='bunn') or (pop=='P') are duplicated, they could be done outside of the loops.". How could that look in my code?

@cJc the easy one would be pop=='P'. what I mean is pop does not change value for all the iteration in the inner loop for (the one on df), so what is possible is to do the equality check before the second for and then you don't need to do it again. like check_pop = pop=='P' between Vector = [] and the for i, e, prod..., then in the if you can replace and ((prod=='bunn') or check_pop )):. Now I<m not sure the gain will be as significant now that your code runs under 2s!!

@cJc for the prod=='bunn', you do it for each iteration of the outer loop for, for the same row of the df. One way would be to create a new column in df with df['Prod_bunn'] = df['Product']=='bunn' before for j, pop..., then use this column directly for i, e, prod_bunn in df[['Start_Date', 'End_Date','Prod_bunn']].to_numpy(): and use it in the if as well: and (prod_bunn  or .... Again, not sure the gain will be siginificant, but hope it gives some ideas on how to rethink code :)

I can't get my head around why the outcomes from your solution and my old version are not the same...

@cJc it is the same reason JonSG mentionned under their answer. if you have several time the same DeliveryStart or Start_Date in your data, try with these 2 dataframes (df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Start_Date':['2024-04-01']*3,'End_Date':['2024-05-01']*3,'Product':['a','a','bunn']}) and h_prof1 = pd.DataFrame({'DeliveryStart': ['2024-04-10']*3,'P_OP':list('NPQ')}) with both methods, and see which one is more what you want, knowing that the dates are all the same and the condition part start<delivery<end is met for all. so the difference comes from the conditions on PoP and product

Every DeliveryStart in h_prof['DeliveryStart'] you take that column, convert it to a list and then try to find the index of the current item j. Then you repeat the same pattern with df['Start_Date']
You probably want to use enumerate() to get the index and value at the same time:
for idx2, j in enumerate(h_prof['DeliveryStart']):

same thing for:
for idx, i in enumerate(df['Start_Date'])


Thanks. It sure makes my code much faster, but interestingly enough the results are not equal... Will need to investigate this..

So, one thing is that my_list.index(my_value) gives you the index of the "first" match where as enumerate() gives you the index of the current item. So there are use cases where one is appropriate and not the other. If you always need the index of the first match (assuming there are duplicates in your list) then we will need to figure out a different solution.

That is a good point to address on the logic about it @cJc. If your h_prof have the same Delivery_Start, for different ids, would you consider the P_OP for the first id only for all your iteration with this Delivery_Start, or you need the P_OP associated to each id (aka row)?

@JonSG How do you mean by index? I use the ['DeliveryStart'] ins datetime format, these looks like: 2025-01-01 00:00:00, 2025-01-01 01:00:00

you seem to use .to_list() a lot, I would recommend using those only once:

h_prof_start = h_prof['DeliveryStart'].to_list()


f_start = df['Start_Date'].to_list()"

and using those in the rest of your code when finding idx and idx2
